# Significance of Limiting Behavior of Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This result comes after establishing the countable additivity of measurable sets in Stein and Shakarchi (2009).

Suppose $E1,E2,...$ are Lebesgue-measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$.
If $(E_k)\uparrow E$, then we have $m(E)=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}m(E_N)$.

Why is this result useful or perhaps significant? Doe this result introduces the notion of continuity in the world of Lebesgue measurable sets?

Reference:
$\textit{Real Analysis: Measure Theory, Integration, and Hilbert Spaces}$. Elias M. Stein, Rami Shakarchi. Princeton University Press, 2009.

Comment: It is very useful. It is a continuity of sorts from the viewpoint of integration - it reads $\int 1_{E_k} \to \int 1_E$.

Comment: @copper.hat  thanks for the comment. would you please provide an example perhaps with an intuitive example using the Lebesgue integration?